# Relative frequencies with dplyr with dynamically created columns pertaining to each group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summary, group-summaries

I'm following [very useful solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24576733/1655567) on creating a summary column for multiple categories. As discussed in the linked solution, I am working with a code that generates the percentage column for each subgroup.

## Relevant sample code from the linked solution:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by (am, gear) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%"))
```

The code generates the desired values:

```
## Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
## Groups: am
## 
##   am gear  n rel.freq
## 1  0    3 15      79%
## 2  0    4  4      21%
## 3  1    4  8      62%
## 4  1    5  5      38%
```

---

## Problem

*I would like modify this code to dynamically created columns pertaining to the unique categories available in the second category passed in the `dplyr` call.* This would be `gear` in case of the attached example. So in case of the attached example, the resulting data frame would look like that:

```
   am gear  n rel.freq_gear3 rel.freq_gear4  rel.freq_gear5
 1  0    3 15      79%            21%
 2  1    4  8      0              62%            38%
```

### Attempts

For a small number of categories I presume that I would be able to make use of the summarising the values in `conditionally`, as discussed [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529691/1655567) where I would try to execute `dplyr` statements only for specified conditions `sumBfoo = sum(B[A=="foo"]))`. However, this approach would be inefficient when dealing with multiple categories. Outside `dplyr` solution could be developed with use of a loop and jumping through unique values of the desired category but my desire would be to do this in `dplyr`.

#### Sample table

Broadly speaking, I would like to create a table similar to the one below:

```
 library(gmodels)
 CrossTable(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear)


   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
| Chi-square contribution |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  32 


             | mtcars$gear 
   mtcars$am |         3 |         4 |         5 | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           0 |        15 |         4 |         0 |        19 | 
             |     4.169 |     1.371 |     2.969 |           | 
             |     0.789 |     0.211 |     0.000 |     0.594 | 
             |     1.000 |     0.333 |     0.000 |           | 
             |     0.469 |     0.125 |     0.000 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           1 |         0 |         8 |         5 |        13 | 
             |     6.094 |     2.003 |     4.339 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.615 |     0.385 |     0.406 | 
             |     0.000 |     0.667 |     1.000 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.250 |     0.156 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |        15 |        12 |         5 |        32 | 
             |     0.469 |     0.375 |     0.156 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

But I'm interested only in *row* proportions without counts and totals and other gadgets.

Comment: This gets you closer but it's not clear to me how you decide to remove some of the rows from the `n`-column. `library(tidyr); count(mtcars, am, gear) %>% mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%")) %>% spread(gear, rel.freq)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks very much for showing the interest in my modest problem. I was also thinking of implementing a way of creating a matrix of sizes **category 1 x category 2** and then inserting values in each cell for a specific combination of groups. Rather onerous solution, I would hope that maybe there is way of doing that in a more efficient manner via `dplyr`.

Comment: There is a similar solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500474/find-proportion-across-categories-grouped-by-a-second-category-using-ddply) using `plyr` that I just found.

Comment: I still don't understand how you removed some of the information (from column "n").. perhaps someone else does.

Comment: I agree, the `n` column in your expected output appears to be wrong. You are also missing a 0 (or NA) in the first row, last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `dplyr`

Building of the comment by `@docendo discimus`:

```
library(tidyr)
count(mtcars, am, gear) %>% 
  mutate(rel.freq = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  spread(gear, rel.freq) %>% 
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(sum2 = sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(perc = paste0(round(100 * ., 0), "%")), -am, -n)
```

Produces:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 5]

     am     n     3     4     5
  (dbl) (int) (chr) (chr) (chr)
1     0    19   79%   21%    0%
2     1    13    0%   62%   38%
```

## `base`

```
prop.table(table(mtcars$am, mtcars$gear), 1) %>% 
  round(2) %>% 
  '*'(100)
```

Produces:

```
   3  4  5
0 79 21  0
1  0 62 38
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution, it's a neat solution. Can I ask, how could I alter the generated columns names. So for example instead of `3` the column name would correspond to `gear_3`?

Comment: `names(output)[-(1:2)] <- paste("gear", names(output)[-(1:2)], sep = "_")`

Comment: Fair enough, daft question on my side. Don't know why, I was thinking on renaming columns inside `dplyr` instead of making use of the `base`.

Comment: There might be a way, but this seems easier.